# Child-theme suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, css, child-theme

I have been working on a [website](http://www.pacificexpress.com.au) using the twenty twelve theme.

I was modifying the footer.php and when I refreshed my website, I noticed all the extra css I had add in my child theme was not working. I reverted the changes I had made in the footer.php, but nothing in my child theme css is being applied to my website.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

**Edit:**

Here is the code -- I do not have what I wrote originally as it was a small edit only, and I just wrote over the top of it. Also I cleared the cache to ensure that I wasn't seeing an old version.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains footer content and the closing of the #main and #page div elements.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>
    </div><!-- #main .wrapper -->
    <footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="site-info">
            <?php do_action( 'twentytwelve_credits' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentytwelve' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, from your link, your website looks nothing like the default twenyt-twelve theme, so your changes does work. Any cache plugins installed maybe? Have you tried another browser, another computer?

Comment: Please do not ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816707/child-theme-stopped-working) on two sites.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a multi-post with an accepted answer on another site.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough rep to add a comment so I have to post an answer. Could you post the footer with and without those changes? This way we can see what you did to the file.

Are you sure the website has not cached it's self for you and you are seeing an out of date version?

Comment: see above i have edited the question.